# Yammer API: return top level group topics

Tags: api, rest, yammer

I'm trying to return just the top level topics in a private group via the rest API but not having much luck.

I can return the messages in the group via

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/" . $groupID . ".json
```

This returns all topics, and the conversation under the topic. I just want to get each topic and ignore the conversation.

I know the result from above contains messages.replied_to_id which is either null or the ID of the topic to which I could filter on my side, but would rather not have to return every conversation, filter them out etc. It seems rather wasteful.

Is there an API option I'm not seeing in their documentation?

(Is topic even the right terminology to use here?)

Comment: Are you trying to return just the thread starters (original message in the thread) and ignore the replies ?

Comment: Exactly, with the threads being in a private group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using the parameter threaded=true, will return only the first message in each thread (thread starter).

Comment: As simple as that aye. Did you find that somewhere in the docs that I missed or..?